# Remote Desktop SSL Nessus Vulnerability 2008R2

Tags: ssl-certificate, windows-server-2008-r2, nessus

I have TLS 1.0 completely disabled in the Registry.  However Nessus still returns an SSL vulnerability for port 3389 which is Remote Desktop. Specifically the certificate.

Why does this come up when TLS 1.0 is turned off?
What is the best option to remediate this?
    - Create my own self signed certificate?
    - Purchase a certificate

I do realize that 2008 r2 is running out of even extended support. However, it will be a year before we're able to replace the servers.  So I'm stuck with patching it the best I can.

I just don't understand why this is an issue with TLS 1.0 turned of.

Thanks in advance for any advice rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Disable TLS 1.0 registry value and there appropriate sub-key value (Client, Server and Protocols)

Generally registry entry does not exist in the registry by default. so create entry and change the DWORD value to 0 for all sub-Key.

Registry location: HKLM SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0

Also Enable TLS 1.2 and disable SSL 2.0 and 3.0 in the Registry.

For more information refer this link https://docs.ukfast.co.uk/operatingsystems/windows/rdp/rdptls.html